# Can't use @Inject() in provided class via useClass

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to replace the default Angular `ErrorHandler` with my own in a sub module I created. However it throw an `NullInjectorError`.

I've narrowed down the issue to revolve around `@Inject(SENTRY_OPTIONS)`. Because when I remove the constructor from `SentryErrorHandler` it starts working.

Problem is. I want to inject the config and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong as I appear to do the same thing as the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action).

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
  // omitted...
  imports: [SentryModule.forRoot(environment.sentry)]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**SentryModule**

```
import {
  ErrorHandler,
  Inject,
  Injectable,
  InjectionToken,
  ModuleWithProviders,
  NgModule,
} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserOptions, captureException, init } from '@sentry/browser';

const SENTRY_OPTIONS = new InjectionToken<BrowserOptions>('SentryOptions');

@Injectable()
export class SentryErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  public constructor(@Inject(SENTRY_OPTIONS) config: BrowserOptions) {
    init(config);
  }

  public handleError(error: Error | any) {
    captureException(error.originalError || error);
    throw error;
  }
}

@NgModule()
export class SentryModule {
  public static forRoot(sentryOptions?: BrowserOptions): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SentryModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: SENTRY_OPTIONS, useValue: sentryOptions },
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: SentryErrorHandler },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

Error

```
Uncaught NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ErrorHandler -> SentryErrorHandler]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ErrorHandler -> SentryErrorHandler]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for SentryErrorHandler!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36537:27)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36864:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36790:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36653:20)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36864:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36790:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36653:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:58301:29)
    at _createClass (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:58369:29)
    at _createProviderInstance (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:58334:26)
```

Comment: Does it help if you put (under `providers`) `SentryErrorHandler` in `@NgModule` decorator of `SentryModule`?

Comment: It didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InjectionTokens` must be exported apparently :-/ 
it's a bit unintuitive as it's only used inside that file.

```
export const SENTRY_OPTIONS = new InjectionToken<BrowserOptions>('SentryOptions');
^^^^^^
```